# Upload image without redirection Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am able to upload file just fine, I just would like to prevent redirecting. That is obviously done by AJAX form submit, but I still end up in the controller which then redirects me.

My Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                //return new ModelAndView("redirect:register");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //return new ModelAndView("redirect:register");
            }
        } else {
            //return new ModelAndView("redirect:register");
        }
    }
```

JSP part:

```
<script>
$('fileUploadForm').submit(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '${home}upload',
        data: $('fileUploadForm').serialize(),
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>


<form id ="fileUploadForm" method="POST" action="upload?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File to upload: <input type="file" name="file">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your controller is not Restfull then you need to indicate to the method that its a restfull call.

Try the below fix.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody // add this
public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {}
```

Comment: I get what you mean and I tried that and I was sure it would work, but it doesn't. Any other suggestion?

Comment: So what does the redirect actually do, does it take you to completely different page or just refreshes the same page?

Comment: It takes me to a different page. To the /upload.

Comment: when you get redirected does the /upload URi also contain CSRF at the end of it? Also does your file get uploaded?

Comment: On both of your questions the answer is yes.

Comment: I have just realized that what I want to achieve is a one user registration form with a file upload (as a profile picture).

Comment: So do you still want to be able to upload a picture at the same time your user registers?

Comment: Yes, and I have already done that. Anyway thanks a lot for trying to help me. I vote up your answer.

Comment: @OndrejTokar not a problem, if you are able to accept it so it closes the question. Appreciate it